# Using VBA to populate richtext field in browser

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, richtextbox

I am using the following code to paste text into a HTML document form. It works with normal text boxes but not with a rich text box.

```
IE.document.getelementId("ct100_ct138...T2").Value = "text" 
IE.document.getelementId("ct100_ct138...RTC14_RTI1_RT1_newRichText").Value = "text"
```

The first line works fine. The second line gives me an error saying "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Save the object that is returned by `IE.document.getelementId("ct100_ct138...RTC14_RTI1_RT1_newRichText")` into a variable and inspect it with the debugger. Is that a control? Does it have a `Value`-property? As far as I know, there is no RichText control in HTML, so it could be that this is a more complex object.

Comment: You can also inspect the element in browser's developer mode and run javascript code there to ensure if it is correct.

Comment: Probably not a "richtext" field - as noted by @FunThomas that's not a thing in HTML - but an HTML element in edit mode (ie. with the `contenteditable` attribute set).   See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: Yes, you have to figure out what "ct100_ct138...RTC14_RTI1_RT1_newRichText" really stands for. You can even use DevTools or IEChooser to inspect the element and then copy the attribute you want.

Comment: https://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/319.htm#:~:text=Rich%20Text%20is%20a%20subset,first%20line%20contains%20a%20tag.